# Import qgis.core to Python IDLE - No module named 'qgis'

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I'm trying to import the qgis.core module as explained here: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html

I'm working on a macOS system and installed python.org Python 3.6. Then I installed qgis.org QGIS 3 and did the following steps:

- Check QGIS install path:

> `QgsApplication.prefixPath()
>   '/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS'`

- Change PYTHONPATH, PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH to:

> `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/:/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Frameworks/`

`export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/`

`export PATH=$PATH:/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs/`

- Write this code into Python IDLE:

> `from qgis.core import *`

- Then I get this error message:

> `Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
>       from qgis.core import *
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qgis'`

Could anyone help me?

Comment: You can't use Anaconda python with QGIS 3 on MacOS, The KyngChaos packages specifically state they are only compatible with Python.org python, not Anaconda/Homebrew/MacPorts/etc... https://www.kyngchaos.com/blog/2018/20180315_qgis_3_must_use_python.org_python_3

Comment: Okay thx. Is it then possible to install now python.org python 3.6 while keeping anaconda python 3.6 on macOS?

Comment: Yes, they shouldn't interfere, just watch out for [this issue](https://xkcd.com/1987).